# How to reboot Ubuntu from Android using SSH?

Tags: ssh

I use SSH to access Ubuntu 18.10 from my Android phone. (I don't think it is important but I do that through a plugin in AIO Launcher.)

The SSH connection works, I am able to turn off/on the volume by `amixer -q -D pulse sset Master toggle`.

But I need to be able to reboot/shut down the computer using my phone and this does not work.

I tested that typing `systemctl reboot` to the command line of my Ubuntu PC reboots the computer (no need to type "sudo"). But typing the same to my phone does nothing. I believe that this is the expected behaviour as I am expected to have superadmin privilegs to restart the computer by SSH. But unfortunately, typing `sudo systemctl reboot` does also nothing (I expected to be asked for my password but it is not the case).

The journal says this about it:

```
Accepted password for ### from ### by (uid=0)
New session 16 of user ###.
Started Session 16 of user ###.
pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [###]
pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ###
Removed session 16.
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe it does "nothing" maybe just not what you're expecting. Are there any errors? What does the journal have to say about this?

Comment: Nothing at all. But this may be caused by the AIO launcher. (This is the first time I am experimenting with SSH so please be patient.) When I tried turning off the volume for the first time, I forgot to previously install openssh-server to my PC. Then I recieved an error message on my phone which was very long but said something like "connection error". But now openssh-server is installed, turning off the volume via SSH works, but both "sudo systemctl reboot" and "systemctl reboot" do nothing, no error message at all.

Comment: What does the journal have to say about this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What journal?

Comment: `journalctl -e` and inspect it around the time you typed `systemctl reboot` or connect a display to the server, and run `journalctl -f` then watch to see if anything posts when you again type `systemctl reboot` (from your phone)

Comment: Thanks. It says: Accepted password for ### from ### by (uid=0); New session 16 of user ###.; Started Session 16 of user ###.; pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed; pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [###]; pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user ###; Removed session 16.

Comment: Please update your post and add this to it using `code` formatting

Comment: `$ sudo shutdown -r now` try this!!

Comment: No luck either...

Comment: Do you have another machine you can ssh from (rather than your phone). Also check your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file to make sure you don't squash any permissions

Comment: No other machine during the next few days. Should I look for something particular in the config file?

Comment: Try a different `ssh` client app in your phone. There are several. I use `JuiceSSH` for Android. I can shutdown or reboot the remote computer from my phone without any problem.

Comment: [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot&hl=en&reviewId=gp%3AAOqpTOElrdkwAR5RRUbtbz_jVYCO-l0UVIHuJZY3OPYKtPE0avhuZMd1tLO-MUry8totXBoZC8BX0acDNPjvASM&showAllReviews=true) is my favorite SSH client for Android.

Comment: Do you actually have sudo privileges on the system? That output from pam_unix makes it look like you don't.

Answer (score 2):

I am using without problems the `sudo reboot` and `sudo poweroff` commands.

Comment: Not working for me.

Comment: Try to change your SSH client software on Android. I am using VX-Connection Bot.